# White screen Magento homepage after migration settings

Tags: magento-2.0.7

When going to our base url we get a white screen on the homepage:

http://95.85.37.169/

We migrated from magento 1.9.0.1 to 2.0.7 and cannot figure out why this is crashing now.

I cannot figure out why it is crashing. This is the code for the homepage where it crashes after:

```
<body data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "http://95.85.37.169/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/nl_NL/images/loader-2.gif"}}' class="cms-index-index page-layout-custom-static-page-one">
        </body>
```

Anybody has a clue?

Comment: Did you get success message after migration?

Comment: Yes @Jai I did get a success message after migration

Comment: Set your theme from admin

Comment: @SHPatel we already did that. It's configured correctly